# Colocar Valor de Parcela dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um Form com 3 input

1 Valor total

2 parcelas

3 Valor da Parcela

Estou precisando que ao colocar o valor total e o numero de parcelas, já preencha o valor da parcela.

alguém tem alguma solução em JavaScript ou Jquery??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desse modo, ao executar um evento na parcela, já calcula o valor por parcela.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Valor Total" id="total">
<input type="text" placeholder="Quantidade parcela" id="parcela">
<input type="text" placeholder="Valor por Parcela" id="valorParcela">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

$('#parcela').change(function(){
var valor        = parseFloat($('#total').val());
var parcela      = parseInt($('#parcela').val());
var totalParcela = valor / parcela;
$('#valorParcela').val(totalParcela);
});
```

Comment: isso, deu certo, mas está muito lento o calculo.

Comment: Eu adicionaria `.toFixed(2)` em `totalParcela` para retornar apenas 2 casas decimais no valor das parcelas.

Comment: Vlw DVdsamm, ficou bem melhor.

Comment: Jean depois dessa alteração que o Dvdsamm falou, ficou mais funcional?

Answer (score 2):

Isso é simples, basta ter auscultadores de eventos que acionem quando houver `input` nos inputs e convertam esse input para numeros.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var total = inputs[0];
var parcelas = inputs[1];
var valorParcelas = inputs[2];

total.addEventListener('input', calcular);
parcelas.addEventListener('input', calcular);

function calcular() {
  valorParcelas.value = Number(total.value || 0) / Number(parcelas.value || 1);
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<label>Total: <input type="text"/></label>
<label>Parcelas: <input type="text"/></label>
<label>Valor da parcela: <input type="text"/></label>
```

Comment: Estou tentando fazer essa forma  `$('#portion').change(function(){
  var valor   = parseFloat($('#total').val())
  var parcela = parseInt($('#portion').val())
  var total = valor / parcela
  $('#moneypar').text(total)
});`

Comment: @JeanPrado ok, se preferes usar jQuery tudo ok. Conseguiste por a funcionar?

Comment: @JeanPrado aqui na Suécia onde vivo já é tarde. Dou uma olhada aqui depois. Mas acho que é melhor usares o evento `input`. O `change` só dispara depois de deixares o foco do elemento.

Comment: sim usei o exemplo do Lucas

Comment: Fico grato, o change está muito lento o calculo.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var valor   = parseFloat($('#total').val())
  var parcela = parseInt($('#parcela').val())
  var total = valor / parcela
  $('#valorParcela').text(total)
  
})
```

```html
  <input type="text" placeholder="valor Total" id="total">
  <input type="text" placeholder="valor Total" id="parcela">
  <div id="valorParcela"></div>
  <button>Gerar</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Segue um exemplo